# Showing there is no local isometry between spheres of different radii

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I wish to show there is no is no local isometry between 2-dim spheres of different radii, without the use of curvature, as it is not in my knowledge yet.

Could you provide directions?

If such isometries preserves area, the contradiction can be reached by considering an equilateral triangle and its image. Though I doubt it's the case.

Comment: Isometries preserve both area and angle, so your idea should work through the judicious application of trigonometry. (Note that when you get to curvature, one interpretation of curvature is the infinitesimal triangle deviation, so this is in some sense an introduction to curvature as an isometry invariant.)